# Как запустить python скрипт на сайте?

Tags: python, django

Хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки на странице, запускался python скрипт, который выполняется длительное время (допустим час). Так вот при нажатии кнопки страница должна просто обновиться и запустить скрипт, который будет выполняться как бы в фоне, чтобы страница не висела. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить, в каком направлении думать или что гуглить?

Comment: Скрипт должен выполняться на сервере?

Comment: @nomnoms12, да, на сервере

Comment: Думаю, Вам будет достаточно создать отдельный поток под эту задачу. Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21945663/11558617

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое)

Comment: @nomnoms12 не очень хорошая идея для хайлоада, но на проектах с 4мя активными юзерами сгодится

Comment: @eri Ага. Раньше я рекомендовал `Celery`, потом `Dramatiq`. Но в итоге склоняюсь к тому, что если человек не знает об этих инструментах, то ему достаточно просто потоков :)

Comment: @nomnoms12, хотел тоже посоветовать развернуть кафка-кластер на кубернетесе, но постеснялся, и написал абстрактно...

Comment: @nomnoms12 ну допустим если у нас деплой на гюникорне.. Какой цикл жизни у потока? Гуникорн не пристрелит воркера, который не завершился после запроса? А если нужны ответы от этого треда... У полинга полно шансов попасть в другой воркер... Я бы соверовал коннект с хттп апгрейднуть до вэбсокета и с него рисовать прогресс-бар

Comment: @eri Вы правы. Не подумал про `timeout` воркера. Тогда выбор специализированных инструментов вполне оправдан.

Comment: @eri а если соединение порвется

Comment: @nomnoms12 фможет там и нет таймаута... Если запускать через рансервер - то точно прокатит. А если деплой, то надо держать в голове как супервайзер себя ведет. На заре джанги супервайзеры работали в префорк

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov а почему оно должно порваться? Даже если оно порвется, то на стороне браузера ты узнаешь что оно порвалось, а на стороне питона останется тот самый тред, который продолжает работу.

Comment: 1) Связь плохая -- соединения рвутся. Как будет вести себя поток с сокетом -- не знаю. 2) Если делать по долгоживущему потоку на запрос, так очень легко нечаянно задосить, надо прикинуть ресурсы. Если задача ресурсоемкая, лучше, чтоб задачи разгребало фиксированное число воркеров (>=1)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите не терять задания, то их надо записывать в очередь с использованием постоянного хранилища, например базы данных.

Запрос с клиента просто пишет данные в очередь.

Специальный **демон** опрашивает очередь и выполняет задания, записывая информацию о ходе исполнения.

В случае рестарта (сервера или демона) демон берет следующее задание из очереди.

При этом следующим может быть в зависимости от потребностей:

- задание, не отмеченное как выполненное (чтобы пробовать снова)
- или задание, не отмеченное как начатое (чтобы пропустить неудачное, оставив в базе)

Comment: Не стесняйтесь конкретики ;)